# How to automatically launch django web server by windows SYSTEM

Tags: python, django, streamlit, windows-server-2019

I want to know if there's a way to have windows server 2019 automatically launch django's web server. I also want the launch to be performed at startup and by SYSTEM.

I tried using batch scripts that launch manage.py from venv's python interpreter. When I launch the batch manually (i.e. double click) it works fine and dandy. But it appears that SYSTEM fails in running the script correctly when planning the task.

I made SYSTEM launch another script at startup (a simple python script that creates a txt file from within its own venv) and it works.
If the Django launch sceipt is launched by USER then it works.

The problem is with the launching of django with SYSTEM. I've also tried streamlit and the result is the same.

Do you have any Ideas?

Sample batch script:

```
cd path\of\managepyfile\
C:\path_to_venv\Scripts\python -m manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I assume you would like SYSTEM to launch the server for its admin rights? In this case, wouldn't it work for what you intend if the USER has admin role?

Comment: @Christophe thanks for the reply. Yes and No. I do have admin rights on the Server. But there are two administrators and I do not want to log in to have the server launched. I would like it that whenever the (virtual) machine starts it launches the server. I do not want to have to log in with any of the two users for this to happen.

Comment: Wrap it in a windows service using a tool like https://github.com/winsw/winsw.  There are others that do a similar thing.  The service can be run as `system`.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the advice, I will look into it!

Comment: unfortunately it seems that I need to building the tool, and unfortunately I cannot. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We run a similar application (not python) but an application that uses a web server.
We have it setup as a task in task scheduler that when the server starts up, it runs the powershell script that executes a command to start the web server.

[Link to setup](https://o365reports.com/2019/08/02/schedule-powershell-script-task-scheduler/)

However, you could use a [web server like IIS](https://medium.com/nonstopio/deploy-django-application-on-windows-iis-server-93aee2864c41) and deploy the files to the www folder in the cdrive and run the site as an IIS service.

Setting it up on IIS was a little tricky if you've never used IIS before. Happy to help out as we have deployed our test access tool for one of our apps this way.

Comment: I Will definitely have a look as soon as possible. Thaks!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not seem to work either.
I think the problem is that SYSTEM does not "like" to launch something like django with the ```python manage.py runserver``` command